# The image of totally disconnected compacta under Lipschitz maps

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The Alexandroff-Hausdorff theorem tells that every compact metric space
is the continuous image of the Cantor set. I am wondering whether the image of a compact totally disconnected  subset in $\mathbb R^n$
 under a Holder-Lipschitz map $L:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$  is totally disconnected again. I know only that sets of measure zero go to sets of measure zero for $m=n$, but this seems to be unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/126691/2060) gives an example of a Lipschitz map with constant $1$ such that the domain is a Cantor set (so totally disconnected) and the image a space homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. So it seems no?